# How to send JSON in a POST request with NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, request

I'm trying to send a POST request to an endpoint which accepts JSON and it doesn't work. Do I have to send any specific parameter in order to let the network know it is encoded as JSON?

Here is the simple request I've so far:

```
var request = require('request')

var cookie = '**Here the cookie copied from the Network tab from the Chrome Dev Tools Bar**'
var UA = '**Here the UA copied from the Network tab from the Chrome Dev Tools Bar**'

var JSONformData = {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"LMT_split_into_sentences","params":{"texts":["Text"],"lang":{"lang_user_selected":"auto","user_preferred_langs":["EN","ES"]}},"id":8}

var URL = 'https://www.deepl.com/jsonrpc'

request.cookie(cookie)
request.post({
        url: URL, 
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': UA
        },
        form: JSONformData
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sending JSON data then you don't need to specify the form, instead specify the json for data in the options object:

```
request.post({
        url: URL, 
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': UA
        },
         json: JSONformData
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response)
    })
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong in your code. Check the docs here: https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback Specifying Json data with json key will set the content type to json and body to the json data.

Comment: As you can see here:
https://github.com/request/request#forms

body: JSON.stringify(...)
That's the point

Comment: What's the point in that? He wanted to send Json data with request module and that's how the docs specify it's done

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu When you use `body: JSON.stringify` you need to set `content-type` to `application/json`. But when you set data to `json` field, request sets it automatically.